# PLS-00330 invalid use of type name or subtype name on package body

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to PL/SQL and I'm trying to create this package, so far I have encountered quite a few problems.

```
create or replace PACKAGE Pkg IS
   TYPE motivos IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   PROCEDURE Proc(lote IN VARCHAR2, e IN NUMBER, obs IN VARCHAR2, motives IN motivos);
END Pkg;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Pkg IS
    PROCEDURE Proc(lote IN VARCHAR2, e IN NUMBER, obs IN VARCHAR2, motives IN motivos) AS
    exist NUMBER(2);
    BEGIN
        SELECT count(*) INTO exist
        FROM Lote l
        WHERE l.numero=lote;

        IF exist>0 THEN
            UPDATE Lote SET empleadoDescarte=e, observacionesDescarte=obs, fechaDescarte=sysdate WHERE numero=lote;
      COMMIT;

            FOR motivo IN motivos           
            LOOP    
                Insert into MOTIVO (NROLOTE, MOTIVO) values (lote,motivo);
            END LOOP;           
      COMMIT;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ok.');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error.');
        END IF;     
    END;
END Pkg;
/
```

When I run this as a script it gives me the following error:

```
Error(13,4): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(13,18): PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
```

The problem is with `exist` and I haven't been able to figure out why by reading the other anwsers related to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in how you use your variables and types; try to edit this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Pkg IS
    PROCEDURE Proc(
                   lote       IN VARCHAR2,
                   e          IN NUMBER,
                   obs        IN VARCHAR2,
                   motives    IN motivos
                  ) AS
        exist                                   NUMBER(2);
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO exist
          FROM Lote l
         WHERE l.numero = lote;

        IF exist > 0
        THEN
            UPDATE Lote
               SET empleadoDescarte         = e,
                   observacionesDescarte    = obs,
                   fechaDescarte            = SYSDATE
             WHERE numero = lote;

            COMMIT;

            FOR i IN motives.first .. motives.last
            LOOP
                INSERT INTO MOTIVO(NROLOTE, MOTIVO)
                     VALUES (lote, motives(i));
            END LOOP;

            COMMIT;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ok.');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error.');
        END IF;
    END;
END Pkg;
/
```

Also, a better naming convention could be useful to easily see issues of this kind; for example, if you call your IN parameters `p_XXX` and your types `ty_XXX`, in every place of the code it's easy to understand what is a parameter, a type, and so on

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your advice